# Winforms application with sql server database?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have a Winforms application. Can I share application folder and use it through the network (multi-user)?

My database attached to SQL Server and I make folder permission `Full control.`

Comment: check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe

Comment: If you want to share the database, then **put it on a server** and have all computers access it there, centrally. Don't start fiddling around with sharing folders and accessing the `.mdf` file over the network - that's a recipe for disaster!